# Manipulating datestamp string consistently with date format %Y%m%d

Tags: bash-scripting, date

I need create log files that are essentially date stamps with prefix `yp_` and suffix `.log`, and a manipulated day number:

```
$ touch yp_$(echo "$(date +%Y%m%d)-10" | /usr/bin/bc -l).log
$ ls
yp_20150912.log   # ... ok for today's date.
```

That's fine for today, but all hell breaks loose when the day's number is between 01 and 10 included.  The result cannot be interpreted as a date stamp any longer.

E.g. just imagine that the day is the 8th of March, 2016, i.e. '20160308'.
How do I code the above to make sure that subtracting 10 days will produce ***not*** '20150298' but '20150227' ?
Also test yr answer with 19820103 ...

-- I looked at `man date`.

-- `apropos date` spews out 161 hits that I also reviewed.

Can somebody help with that one-liner?

Comment: GNU `date`, out of interest?

Comment: @bertieb: Yup, GNU date it is.  My first example IS a leap-year !

Comment: Welp, GNU `date` to the rescue then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### I need to manipulate dates (whilst paying attention to leap years)

Fortunately, `GNU date` has a *very handy* `-d` option:

> ```
> -d, --date=STRING
>           display time described by STRING, not 'now'
> ```

*(from `man date`)*

This accepts arbitrary date descriptions, like "now + 1 year" "Jan 28 + 3 weeks"; or in your case: "now - 10 days":

```
touch yp_$(date -d 'now - 10 days' +%Y%m%d).log
```

No need for messy invocations of `bc`, no worrying about leap years- GNU `date` will handle it.

Comment: Right on. This is _exactly_ what I had in mind AND I had seen that option on the man page, but had not understood its use. Thanks - PS:  BTW the "land of rain and drink" could be a lot of places... any place north of me, actually. :))

Comment: @Cbhihe Glad it worked for you- it's an incredibly useful thing to know about (and a feature I miss when not available in other languages) :) PS about 55° N, and rain on more days than not- make of what what you will ;)

Answer (score 6):

To display a formatted date for x-days from today:

```
$ echo $(date +%Y%m%d)
20150922

$ echo $(date -d -10days +%Y%m%d)
20150912

$ echo $(date -d +10days +%Y%m%d)
20151002
```

Comment: I liked the concision of your answer and the answer is dead right. But it just came after @bertieb 's own, which is equally right. So I can only upvote you. Tx Steven and sorry for that.